# Kotlin Android - How to set app window size for chrome book/ os

Tags: android, kotlin, chromebook, androidappsonchromeos

I made a stand alone andoird app w/c is to be used in a chromeOS desktop.  I used Kotlin and when I installed the app and when it runs, it goes full screen and I have to adjust it down to the desired size.  I think this is because of match_parent in my xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

I just want it to open up at a fixed size, probably a 4th of the monitor size.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/window-management

Comment: Yeah, just saw that page.  I tried adding the line <layout android:defaultHeight="500dp"  android:defaultWidth="800dp"/>   But I get a warning saying "element layout is not allowed here".  I placed them in my manifest under the main activity.

Comment: You might want to edit your question and post your `<layout>` element in context.